# BigQuery - NULL values

Tags: null, google-bigquery

I want to make calculation among columns, which contains null values

```
x1     x2
9      0.0
5      1.2
12     null
10     null
```

If calculation

```
x1 + (x1*x2)
```

is made, it results in

```
9, 6, null, null
```

Can you pls suggest, how null values can be handled, so the result will be

```
9, 6, 12, 10
```

I was trying ifelse, if value is null, then use 1

```
IF(x1 = null, 0, x1)
```

but the results is still with null values.

Thank you!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use `IFNULL(expr, 0)` - this will come back as 0 if `expr` is null.

In general, instead of doing `something=null` do `something IS null`.

Comment: And the reason is that any expression involving null (aside from "IS NULL" and "IFNULL") will evaluate to null, even if that expression is something like "foo = null".

Answer (score 6):

**Use [ifnull](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#ifnull) function in Google Big Query.** (Link provided)

```
IFNULL(x1, 0)*IFNULL(x2,0) as new_col
```

- This will plug in 0 in place of any null values in x1 and x2.

FYI: There is a `ISNULL(column_name)` in Google cloud Data Prep just like in MySQL that will return a boolean i.e either True or False depending upon the column is null or not.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution is using COALESCE(arg1, arg2, ...,argN)
Which returns the first not null argument.

For example:

`COALESCE(x1 , 0) * COALESCE(x2, 0)`  returns 0 if x1 (or x2) is null.